# Pyomo: print the constraint that causes the error

Tags: printing, pyomo, ipopt

I am using ipopt in pyomo, I have the next error:

```
Error evaluating constraint 15: can't compute -1.65898/0.
halt_on_ampl_error=yes
```

How can I print the constraint name that causes the error in pyomo?

Something like the AMPL command: `print _sconname[15];`

Thanks, M.

Answer (score 3):

That error is being thrown by the ASL when evaluating an expression during the solution process (i.e., it is not a Pyomo error).

The trick to making the error more intelligible is to ask Pyomo to pass "symbolic" labels to the solver.  This is disabled by default for efficiency reasons: generating human-readable labels is more expensive than simply numbering constraints and variables and users rarely interact with the raw model that is sent to the solver.

- If you are using the `pyomo` command, then you can pass the `--symbolic-solver-labels` option:

  ```
  pyomo solve --solver ipopt --stream-solver --symbolic-solver-labels #...
  ```
- If you are scripting, then you want to set the `symbolic_solver_labels=True` in the `solve()` call:

  ```
  SolverFactory('ipopt').solve(model, tee=True, symbolic_solver_labels=True)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do the mapping to specifically identify the constraint you want but another option is to go through your model and reformulate any constraints that divide by a variable that is not bounded away from zero. You should also provide a good initialization for all of your variables or at the very least initialize them to a value other than zero.